# Keep scrollbar sticky to bottom of window Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the following I have built: https://play.tailwindcss.com/TNyt801jvi

Now I am struggling to keep the scroll bar sticky at the bottom of the page/window no matter the content height.

Is anyone able to help me here? tried various height attributes but nothing changes.

[image]

Comment: The horizontal scroll bar on Windows on Chrome seems to always be at the bottom for me – consider clarifying what platform you are viewing the webpage such that the scroll bar moves?

Comment: I have added a screenshot to better explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider applying `min-height: 100vh` via the `min-h-screen` utility class to the scrolling container:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="shrink-0">
    <div class="py-10"></div>
    <div class="p-4">
      <p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-left font-sans text-lg font-semibold">PHP</p>
      <p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-left font-sans text-base font-normal">This is the description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="p-4">
      <p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-left font-sans text-lg font-semibold">JavaScript</p>
      <p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-left font-sans text-base font-normal">This is the description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="p-4">
      <p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-left font-sans text-lg font-semibold">React</p>
      <p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-left font-sans text-base font-normal">This is the description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-1 flex-row space-x-10 overflow-auto min-h-screen">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-brand mb-2 text-center font-sans text-3xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight">Bob</h2>
        <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10"><p class="text-brand line-clamp-none text-center font-mono text-base font-normal">Proficiency</p></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-10 p-6">
        <button type="button" class="whitespace-no-wrap focus:shadow-outline-danger relative flex h-12 w-12 shrink-0 items-center justify-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white transition duration-300 hover:bg-red-600 focus:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none active:bg-red-600 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:bg-red-400">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-3 whitespace-pre"><div>1</div></div>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To address the comment regarding with a header, consider using a vertical flex or a grid layout:

```html
<div class="grid grid-rows-[auto_1fr] min-h-screen">
  <header class="py-20">
    This is the header of the page
  </header>
  <div class="flex">
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/9UvwCXP7Ah

Comment: Could potentially work, but sorry one other thing to add is I have a header on the page. So i would like the scroll bar to still be visible and not below the fold

https://play.tailwindcss.com/TNyt801jvi

Comment: Added solution with regards to a header.

Comment: I think that could work with some tweaking (e.g. left side should remain static and fix the double scroll bars).
But thanks, will give it a try now!